# Android Notification Click to Broadcast Receiver getting same intent string

Tags: java, android

I have a broadcast receiver which is triggered on a notification click. I'm passing a string in the intent of notification for the broadcast receiver. The values of the string differs everytime however when I am testing my app, I can only see the value I received the first time I clicked the notification. Now every value I'm getting from my notification to the broadcast receiver is same despite passing new values.

My code:

```
//Creating notification
Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceLauncherBroadcast.class);
        snoozeIntent.putExtra("order_id", orderId);

//In the broadcast receiver
startWorkManager(intent.getStringExtra("order_id")

//Manifest 
<receiver android:name = ".utils.ServiceLauncherBroadcast" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PendingIntent please use this flag:

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. I guess this flag made the previous broadcast canceled and get a fresh new one.